# Dropzonejs without Form

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Is there any way to use Dropzone js without using Form. 
I want to use like following.But in this way image preview is not showing.

```
    <div class="dropzone" id="dropzoneForm">
      <div class="fallback">
       <input name="file" type="file" multiple/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Read more through  in the [**`docs`**](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) and it will explain many problems people faces these days.. Anyways Here is the solution to your problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dropzone.css" />
    <script src="dropzone.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", {
        url: "/file/post"
      });
      $("div#myId").dropzone({
        url: "/file/post"
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="myId" class="fallback dropzone">
      <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
  </body>
```

What im doing here is giving the div a url to link to so you dont have to use a form!

Comment: Thanks for response.Can you please explain what does that url:"/file/post" do? I couldn't post images along with other field values of the same form to a method in asp.net mvc.

Comment: Yes you can totaly post images @setu ! The url is like the action="/file/post" in the form tag.. Understand?

Comment: The question asked in that page is not related to the question you are asking now @setu .

Comment: And sadly @setu i dont know any C#

Comment: The real question here is... Did you understand how to solve the problem that was asked in this page @setu .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107385/discussion-between-setu-and-amanuel-bogale).

Comment: does this work when the div is inside a form?
i currently have a dropzone inside the form but i want to add another dropzone and html doesn't allow nested forms.

Comment: it is giving me 419. can u share complete config for dropzone

Comment: Must add `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;`

Comment: In the `<script>` element you are showing both JavaScript and JQuery solutions, which is confusing. Need to add an explanation for this.